# problems in semantic installation ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

after setting up  semantic folder in my project folder i get an error when i use 'gulp build' command:

```
aayush@aayushs-computer:~/Desktop/NewP$ sudo npm install semantic-ui
[sudo] password for aayush: 
npm WARN deprecated gulp-clean-css@2.4.0: breaking changes from clean-css 4.x. Please install gulp-clean-css 3.x
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN prefer global js-beautify@1.5.10 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

> semantic-ui@2.2.10 install /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP/node_modules/semantic-ui
> gulp install

[20:19:41] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/NewP/node_modules/semantic-ui/gulpfile.js
[20:19:41] Starting 'install'...

[20:19:41] Starting 'run setup'...
? Set-up Semantic UI Express (Set components and output folder)
?     
    We detected you are using NPM. Nice!  

    Is this your project folder?
    /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP 


 Yes
? Where should we put Semantic UI inside your project? semantic/
? What components should we include in the package? reset, site, button, contain? Should we set permissions on outputted files? No
? Do you use a RTL (Right-To-Left) language? No
? Where should we output Semantic UI? out
[20:20:46] Finished 'run setup' after 1.08 min
[20:20:46] Starting 'create install files'...







Installing
------------------------------
Installing to semantic/
Copying UI definitions
Copying UI themes
Copying gulp tasks
Adding theme files
Creating gulpfile.js
Creating site theme folder /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP/semantic/src/site/
[20:20:46] Starting 'create theme.config'...
Adjusting @siteFolder to:  site/
Creating src/theme.config (LESS config) /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP/semantic/src/theme.config
[20:20:46] Finished 'create theme.config' after 21 ms
[20:20:46] Starting 'create semantic.json'...
Creating config file (semantic.json) /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP/semantic.json
[20:20:46] Finished 'create semantic.json' after 20 ms
[20:20:46] Finished 'create install files' after 177 ms
[20:20:46] Starting 'clean up install'...

 Setup Complete! 
 Installing Peer Dependencies. Please refrain from ctrl + c... 
 After completion navigate to semantic/ and run "gulp build" to build

> fsevents@1.1.2 install /home/aayush/Desktop/NewP/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN newp@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ semantic-ui@2.2.10
added 681 packages in 133.426s
aayush@aayushs-computer:~/Desktop/NewP$ cd sematic/
bash: cd: sematic/: No such file or directory
aayush@aayushs-computer:~/Desktop/NewP$ cd semantic/
aayush@aayushs-computer:~/Desktop/NewP/semantic$ gulp build
No command 'gulp' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gslp' from package 'ghostscript' (main)
gulp: command not found
```

i have read and tried all things in https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2086. problem still there.